# Boost Solr query same as ORDER BY MySQL

Tags: solr

I run this query in Solr:

```
select?q=(num_int:83 OR num_int:82 OR num_int:84) AND (config_ban_id:118)&start=0&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true
```

What I want is to boost the first `num_int`. If Solr finds 83, then it shows the row first. If not, it shows results for 82 and 84.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've added some formatting to your question, but unfortunately I don't understand the last part. Could you please [edit] it and explain what you mean this? "What I want is to boost the first `num_int`. If Solr finds 83, then it shows the row first. If not, it shows results for 82 and 84."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to boost term 83, you could apply [query time boosting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-BoostingaTermwith_), by applying `^` operator.

Something like this will boost 83 over 82 or 84.

```
q=(num_int:83^10 OR ...
```

In case you have arbitrary order between 83, 82 and 84 you could apply boost to the next in order value as well, e.g.

```
q=(num_int:83^10 OR num_int:82^5 OR num_int:84^2)
```